# How to pass very many options to ImageMagick?

Tags: zsh, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick to compose many images.

```
for counter in {1..$limit}
do
  partial=...
  x=...
  y=...
  convert $canvas
    $partial -geometry "+$x+$y" -composite
    $canvas
done
```

Basically I am mogrifying N images, one-at-a-time.

Right now my `$limit` is small and the script runs in reasonable time. But `$limit` will increase to thousands of images in the future.

I am considering to build the `convert` command to include all the partials at once. Then only run `convert` once. ImageMagick claims [it can work with terabit](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) images no problem. So I imagine giving thousands of tasks at once should not be a problem.

The issue is that shell limits the number of arguments you can pass to a program. Can I pass all the arguments to ImageMagick in some other way, like a script file? And is this a bad idea?

Comment: Neither `{1..$limit}` or `$var = value` will work in any shell; please post some real example instead of "pseudo-code". I would rather some scripting language bindings in your stead -- I found perl's Image::Magick much more logical and easier to use than the ornery command line interface; and that's probably the same in python, etc.

Comment: Removed erroneous $ before vars in assignment. Clarified this is zsh. That counter works in zsh, try it: `for a in {1..$$}; do echo $a; done`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass ImageMagick options from a file, by passing it an `@filename` argument, in which case ImageMagick will read the arguments from the passed file.

From [the documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php) (see section "File References"):

> Some ImageMagick command-line options may exceed the capabilities of your command-line processor. Windows, for example, limits command-lines to 8192 characters. If, for example, you have a draw option with polygon points that exceed the command-line length limit, put the draw option instead in a file and reference the file with the `@` (e.g. `@mypoly.txt`).

So that feature is designed specifically to curb around limitations in command-line length and number of arguments.

Comment: if you gave an example, that would be great. `convert @argsfile` doesn't work on any of my systems, only `gm convert @argsfile` does, but that's GraphicsMagick, not ImageMagick.

Comment: Thank you, and is the any reason to believe that passing a ridiculous number of options would be a problem?

Comment: @WilliamEntriken Updated to include snippet from documentation which mentions it. It seems the feature is designed specifically to curb around number of arguments in the command-line, even though they mention a much lower limit, so unsure whether it will really suit your needs completely...

Comment: I have played around with this and it does not work for arguments other than file names. For smaller tests, `magick $(cat script.tmp)` will work but `magick @script.tmp` will not.

Answer (score 0):

You can put lots of **ImageMagick** commands in a script and tell it to execute them. I don't really know what your partial commands are, so I decided to draw 10,000 circles of random colour, size and position, so hopefully you can adapt to your specific problem:

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

out="script.mgk"

# Define width and height of the image
W=512
H=512

# Create the initial canvas
echo "-size ${W}x${H} xc:" > $out

# Draw 10,000 randomly-sized, randomly-coloured circles on it
for ((i=0;t<=10000;t++)) ; do
   ((cx=$RANDOM % W))         # x-coordinate of circle centre
   ((cy=$RANDOM % H))         # x-coordinate of circle centre
   ((r=$RANDOM % 30))         # radius of circle
   ((cx2=cx+r))               # x-coordinate of point on circumference 
   ((red=$RANDOM %255))       # random red in range 0..255
   ((green=$RANDOM % 255))    # random green in range 0..255
   ((blue=$RANDOM % 255))     # random blue in range 0..255
   echo "-fill rgb(${red},${green},${blue}) -draw \"circle ${cx},${cy} ${cx2},${cy}\""
done >> $out

echo "-write result.png" >> $out
```

If you run it, it creates a file called `script.mgk` that looks like this:

```
-size 512x512 xc:
-fill rgb(44,228,226) -draw "circle 54,274 77,274"
-fill rgb(59,118,147) -draw "circle 242,231 258,231"
-fill rgb(70,91,229) -draw "circle 418,95 436,95"
-fill rgb(26,16,153) -draw "circle 148,128 148,128"
...
... thousands of lines omitted
...
-fill rgb(130,67,183) -draw "circle 15,326 23,326"
-fill rgb(152,79,104) -draw "circle 409,155 438,155"
-write result.png
```

You can now execute that like this:

```
magick -script script.mgk
```

[image]

---

### Note 1

You could create the 512x512 background image on the command line, rather than in the script and then run the script to continue work on an image you previously created/loaded:

```
magick -size 512x512 xc: -script script.mgk
```

### Note 2

You can obviate the need to create a temporary script on disk and pipe the commands directly to **ImageMagick** like this:

```
for ((i=0;i<10;i++)) ; do
  echo "-draw ..."
done | magick -script -
```

There is a better example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/721860/400632).