# How can I use one input file into several separate operations

Tags: shell, scripting, memory, images, imagemagick

I would like to read one file, do an operation with several different parameters on it and finally save each output as a separate file.

Currently I do it as shown in the code snipped below.
This reads the image each iteration, while in fact I do not change it.
For larger images (these here are 400 MB) it becomes quit a slow process.
Memory is large enough and it would be fine to load it into memory once and process it from there. But I am unsure how to do this. Not in a shell nor with ImageMagick.

1. Is there a `ImageMagick`-native way to do this?
2. Would it be the easiest to just copy the file once on a Memory Mapped file system and use the script below?

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

FILE=foo.tif
i=65;END=80;STEP=1
while [ $i -le $END ]; do
convert $FILE -threshold ${i}\% ${i}.png &
i=$((i+$STEP))
done
```

It would be great if the *shell part* would stay POSIX compliant.
EDIT: I launch sub-processes in the background to utilize the cores I got.

Comment: Your system should normally cache the input file in memory when it is read repeatedly. I guess the time is needed either for the calculation in `convert` or for writing the output files. You could try to analyze this with a system call trace or profiling. (For the latter you might need to recompile `convert` with profiling enabled.)

Comment: Use `mvtouch -l` if you can. But the above comment is good, maybe the bottleneck is elsewhere.

Comment: When $FILE is cached, the program becomes CPU-bound. A simpler, though less precise method than @Bodo's is using tools that measure IO and CPU load, e.g. `vmstat`, `iostat`, `top` or `iotop`. If CPU utilization is 100% or close, it's likely that disk IO is not the limiting factor. As @Bodo says,  you also write files, which will eventually be flushed to the disk. The bottleneck could be at that level.

Comment: Thanks you all for your suggestions. It turned out the transformation from .tif to .png is where the CPU hat to do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

The *easiest* way to do this is with **GNU Parallel**, which results in more or less exactly the same sequence of operations as your script (in terms of processes and parallelism), but is much more concise.

So, starting with this image:

[image]

You could run:

```
parallel magick image.jpg -threshold {}% {}.jpg ::: {65..80}
```

which gets you the following if I animate the sequence:

[image]

---

If you want to load the image just once and do several operations, you really need a magick script. So you could generate one like this:

```
for ((t=65;t<=80;t++)) ; do
   printf "( -clone 0 -threshold ${t}%% -write ${t}.jpg +delete )\n"
done
```

That will generate a script like this:

```
( -clone 0 -threshold 65% -write 65.jpg +delete )
( -clone 0 -threshold 66% -write 66.jpg +delete )
( -clone 0 -threshold 67% -write 67.jpg +delete )
( -clone 0 -threshold 68% -write 68.jpg +delete )
( -clone 0 -threshold 69% -write 69.jpg +delete )
( -clone 0 -threshold 70% -write 70.jpg +delete )
( -clone 0 -threshold 71% -write 71.jpg +delete )
( -clone 0 -threshold 72% -write 72.jpg +delete )
( -clone 0 -threshold 73% -write 73.jpg +delete )
( -clone 0 -threshold 74% -write 74.jpg +delete )
( -clone 0 -threshold 75% -write 75.jpg +delete )
( -clone 0 -threshold 76% -write 76.jpg +delete )
( -clone 0 -threshold 77% -write 77.jpg +delete )
( -clone 0 -threshold 78% -write 78.jpg +delete )
( -clone 0 -threshold 79% -write 79.jpg +delete )
( -clone 0 -threshold 80% -write 80.jpg +delete )
```

So, if you wrote that to a file called `script.mgk`, you could run it like this:

```
magick image.jpg -script script.mgk
```

and re-use the script many times over.

---

Or, you could generate it *"on-the-fly"* (without temporary file creation) and pipe it into **ImageMagick** like this:

```
for ((t=65;t<=80;t++)) ; do 
   printf "( -clone 0 -threshold ${t}%% -write ${t}.jpg +delete )\n"
done | magick image.jpg -script -
```

That generates the same result as above, but is POSIX-compliant, and hopefully you can see it only starts a single instance of **ImageMagick**, and only loads the input image once, then re-uses it.